# Is "torsion continuity" a misnomer for G³ geometric continuity?

Tags: continuity, curves, plane-curves, spline

I've recently been researching [parametric vs geometric continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Geometric_continuity) of splines (piecewise polynomials) in 2D space.

The most common terms for each level of geometric continuity are:

- $G^0$ is positional continuity
- $G^1$ is tangential continuity
- $G^2$ is curvature continuity
- $G^3$ is torsion continuity

These all make perfect sense to me - except "torsion continuity" for $G^3$

One [paper I've been reading](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA611758.pdf), generalizes $G^n$ geometric continuity using so called $\beta$-parameters, so that any level of $G^n$ continuity can be achieved, *regardless of the number of spatial dimensions of the spline*

I have also implemented $G^3$ for 2D bézier splines, and it [can be visualized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jE3Z.png) using curvature combs. Note how the curvature comb itself has a tangent continuous join for $G^3$, unlike in $G^2$

Now, the concept of [torsion of a curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_of_a_curve) is stated as follows:

> the torsion of a curve measures how sharply it is twisting out of the osculating plane

However, as far as I can tell, the torsion of a 2D curve is *always* $0$ - this seems directly in contradiction of the fact that constraining curves by "torsion
continuity" ($G^3$) still works fine in 2D

Is calling $G^3$ "torsion continuity" a misnomer?

Comment: $$\begin{cases}[1,\sin(t),\cos(t)]&&0\leq t\leq \pi/2\\
[\sin(t),1,\cos(t)]&&\pi/2\leq t\leq \pi\end{cases}$$ is $G^1$ with constant curvature but is not $G^2$.

Comment: I think the more precise definitions of $G^2$ usually specify that they have to also share the same center of curvature, not just the scalar value of the curvature itself, which would be discontinuous in this case, as it should be. Similarly, you can have $G^0$ curves that have fully continuous curvature, but since they don't match the other criteria they fail to be $G^1$ and $G^2$

Comment: G2 usually means G1 plus matching (scalar) curvature. This implies that centers of curvature are also equal.

Comment: it seems to me like the curve @Coolwater posted above shouldn't be classified as $G^2$ though, no? I thought center of curvature was required - the curvature combs in 3D wouldn't line up in that example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a misnomer. I'd say that G3 means that the derivatives of both curvature and torsion (with respect to arclength) are continuous at the junction. Continuity of torsion alone is a much weaker condition.

In design applications where people care about G3, they're usually working with planar curves. They will check that the curvature combs join smoothly (as you did), or they will check that surface reflections are G2. Obviously, in this scenario, torsion is irrelevant, since the torsion of a planar curve is always zero.